# Problems reading from Microsoft Messaging Queues in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, msmq

I have problems reading from my MSMQ. When I write to the queue, it works perfectly, but when I try to read that message from the queue, I get the following exception: "The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation." The queue does exists, and I have full permissions on the machine and queue. Here is my code:

```
 public string path = @".\private$\";

 public void WriteToQueue(string QueueName, object messageObject)
 {
    try
    {
        path = path +  QueueName;
        MessageQueue msmq = null;

        if (!MessageQueue.Exists(path))
        {
            msmq = MessageQueue.Create(path);
        }
        else
        {
            msmq = new MessageQueue(path);

        }
         msmq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(string)});
         msmq.Send(messageObject);
         msmq.Close();
        }
        catch (MessageQueueException ex)
        {
            System.ArgumentException argEx = neArgumentException(ex.ToString());
            throw argEx;
        }

        path = @".\private$\";
    }


 public string ReadQueue(string QueueName)
 {
     try
     {
         path = path + QueueName;

         MessageQueue msmq = new MessageQueue(path);

         string msg;
         msmq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(string)});

         msg = msmq.Receive().Body.ToString();  //exception is thrown here
         path = @".\private$\";

         return msg;
        }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

can the problem maybe be with reading it as type of string?  Maybe not in the right format?

Comment: Changing the *path* field in the methods is a Really Bad Idea.  One exception and your code will stop working.  With an exception that's just like you describe.  Use a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public string path = ".\\private$\\";
```

'@' doesn't work for me too.